# What is the fastest way of searching a list of regexs in a text using Python?

Tags: python, regex

Assuming that I have the following list:

```
l = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

I'm wondering what is the fastest method to search a large text and return `True` if any of the strings exists in the text?

Comment: Not using regex. It's overhead for simple strings.

Comment: If those are literally the strings you are looking for; `'foo' in s or 'bar' in s or 'baz' in s`. If not those, it depends on the search strings and the target string. What have you tried, how slow is it, and by what factor is it too slow?

Comment: How are you defining *"in"*? Case sensitive? Only the whole word?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I mean case-insensitive occurrences.

Comment: Define "large text"? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: If your text is `truefully` and your list is `['fully']` what do you expect the return to be? i.e., only look for whole words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
text = 'slfdk gaklsdjfl asdkfljasdkljf qkwlejlqwekj bazaklajsdfkj gsadf'
l = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

print any(e in text for e in l)
```

Comment: `any` already short-circuits, if you take away the `[]` and make the list comprehension into a generator expression.

Comment: @taesu, does `print any(e in text for e in l)` stop when it finds the first instance?

Comment: @Paulrx as jonrsharpe pointed out, it short-circuits, so yes. and I did not know that.

Comment: Alright, how can I compare the execution time with when using `re` ?

Comment: do some [profiling](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) on large set of input, but it is usually the case that string operation is preferable vs. regex operations.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `in` keyword you can do this easily :

```
def wordInText(list, text):
  for word in list:
    if word in text: return True
  return False

wordInText(['test', 'cat', 'exam'], 'this is a simple example') # returns True
wordInText(['test', 'cat', 'max'], 'this is a simple example') # returns False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = 'fgfkgfgujndf foofsdjbnfbarfkdfmdsf'

l = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
found = re.findall('|'.join(l), s)
if found:
    print found
```